# Windows 10 so many processes running in the background

Tags: windows

I am using windows 10 and there are 70 background processes and 30 apps running in the background.
I have only drivers installed and no other software has been installed. I have also disabled background apps from settings and also deleted every windows 10 build in app I could using powershell.
Is this normal in windows 10?

Comment: looks like you run into [this "issue"](https://superuser.com/a/1212692/174557)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal for the out-of-the-box installation to have 70 processes running.
Using [SysInternals Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) would show that many of them are actually services that are on by default, and some others are system processes.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, I will say yes. With Windows 10 Task Manager you are able to see a number of tasks running as `system`.

For example, if I run Google Chrome (1x Tab) I have the following processes listed in task manager:

[image: Chrome Process]

If you are unsure of a process, you can search online using task manager:

[image: Task Manager]

There are (to my knowledge) no updated process list for windows applications, however