# Two svchost.exe processes keeps occpying 25% (sum) CPU on Windows 10 Pro 1709

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, cpu, windows-10-v1709

I got a new Thinkpad T470 laptop, which is supposed to have "10+ hours of battery life". However, there are these two `svchost.exe` processes that keep taking a sizable bite on my CPU.

My guess for now is that: these two processes are started by the `WiFi Hotspot` "service".

#### Details of the two processes

```
Image Name                     PID Services
========================= ======== ============================================
    svchost.exe                   4144 BFE, CoreMessagingRegistrar, MpsSvc
    svchost.exe                  14108 SharedAccess
```

I used `tasklist /SVC` to elicit the above info, and used [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to monitor the CPU usage. What follows is a GIF on how persistent these two processes are (screen-recorded from Process Lasso, a paid piece of software).
[image]

#### Failed Attempts

Here goes a list of failed debugging attempts:

1. After spending a good hour with Microsoft Support people through a remote session, I was advised to [conduct a "clean boot"](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/what-is-clean-boot-state-in-windows), by disabling all services. They also said I don't have to manually disable all startup processes/items in the Task Manager. It did not help:

   - Indeed, the Microsoft people's job is done after the "clean boot": s\he is no longe connected and I can no longer bother him or her; yet, what I get from the **"clean boot"** is nothing but a crappy solution:

     - For sure, these two processes are no longer bothering me, upon system start;
     - However, when I want to start the WiFi Hotspot, they are back again.
     - And, the WiFi Hotspot just gets stuck there: always in progress, and no other devices can connect to it.
2. Potentially, this may have to do with a third party software Connectify. Uninstalling it does not help: starting WiFi Hotspot through Windows Setting should no longer generate a usable WiFi, and the two `svchost.exe` process should still be running in the background, at all times.
3. I have tried to run Windows Updates, and Thinkpad Driver updates. It does not help. And, the system is `Windows 10 Pro 1709`.
4. I have also tried to manually stop the two services. Of course, this only helps with generating a "Blue Screen" and entails the BOIS to reload. (A system restart thereby follows.)

#### Question: does it cost 20% CPU to run WiFi Hotspot?

I need to generate a WiFi Hotspot for personal use, in my work environment. There is a piece of reading device that I literally "live on", which needs a *home wifi* to sync with the PC. Preferably, this "home wifi" ought to be running 24/7, through the WiFi Hotspot.

And, if it should not cost one 20% CPU to simply run a WiFi Hotspot, what should I do to debug this consistent CPU usage from the two aforementioned `svchost.exe` processes?

#### Question: how to resume WiFi Hotspot connectivity?

As answered in this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1260614/after-windows-10-fall-creators-update-a-svchost-exe-instance-is-constantly-usin), one can disable all internet sharing services and get away with a lower CPU usage. Sure, this helps, but does not solve my issue: **I would like to have a WiFi Hotspot running, at all times, with lower CPU usage**. Disabling everything is not an equivalent to a satisfactory solution.

**To whom that has closed this question, please enable the `Answer` button for me**. I will provide more info on why this happened (tentatively a driver issue), and my tentative solution.

Comment: Could this be related: https://superuser.com/questions/1260614/after-windows-10-fall-creators-update-a-svchost-exe-instance-is-constantly-usin#comment1854752_1260614

Comment: Hi @HelpingHand, thank you for pointing out another more traceable channel to debug the problems. I think the services that caused the problem, should have been identified: ` BFE, CoreMessagingRegistrar, MpsSvc` and `SharedAccess`, where the letter is alias for the formal "Internet Connection Sharing (ICE)" entry in the `Services` list. Yet, disabling either one seems to also disable the WiFi Hotspot connection?