# Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) service stuck at starting

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-shares, services, ics

I'm used to use this service because I like to use my wireless card as a hotspot, but since yesterday the service doesn't start anymore. The last time I tried to enable connection sharing, COM Surrogate stopped responding so I saw ICS service was stuck at "starting" and never starts. I already restarted my computer, checked service's dependencies, disabled firewall and nothing worked.

What's going on?

Comment: Have you had a look in your event viewer?

Comment: @spikey_richie, yes, but I've see nothing special. When I disabled service and enabled manually after restart, I get the error 1053: "the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion".

Comment: Presumably this is on a mobile device (laptop/tablet) using an onboard SIM card and sharing that connection out via wifi?

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft, yes, a laptop but not SIM card. I want to share my Ethernet connection via wifi. I did it a lot of times, but since yesterday this problem started.

Comment: [The answer](https://superuser.com/q/1260614/150988#1261114) to [that other question](https://superuser.com/q/1260614/150988) says, “As was later discovered in [the TenForums post](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/95844-fall-update-v-1709-creates-problems-cpu-usage-desktop-wallpaper.html "Fall update v.1709 creates problems: CPU usage and others …"), resetting Windows Defender Firewall fixes this issue.”  Have you tried that?

Comment: @Scott, yes! I misunderstood that line. My bad. I discovered the solution by myself after hours. I did exactly this. I'm so sorry, it should be marked as duplicate indeed.