# High CPU usage when doing nothing

Tags: windows-10, performance, task-manager, svchost

I am trying to optimize a user's laptop PC which has become very sluggish. It's a 10-year-old Dell Inspiron 1545 with a single-core Intel Celeron running at 2.2 GHz, with 3 GB RAM, running 64-bit Windows 10 with the latest updates (Fall Creators Update, 10.0.16299).

Although grossly under-powered by today's standards, it used to work just fine for the user's purposes (web browsing, email and word processing) when it was running Windows 7. It seems to have slowed down when Windows 10 was automatically installed and possibly continued slowing down ever since.

I've looked at existing questions on the Internet but none of the suggestions so far worked.

When the laptop is sitting there doing nothing, it's using 91% CPU. Memory usage is 50% (1.5 GB out of 3 GB). Disk activity is between 0 and 2%. It has a single C: drive with just 61 GB in use and 157 GB free. A full virus scan using paid-for AVG Internet Security shows no threats.

There are two processes using the bulk of the CPU, both `svchost.exe`:

- Service Host: Local Service (No Network) - 53% CPU, 4 services:

  - Windows Defender Firewall
  - Diagnostic Policy Service
  - CoreMessaging
  - Base Filtering Engine
- Service Host: Local System - 34% CPU, 17 services:

  - Windows Push Notifications System Service, WMI, User Manager, Web Account Manager, Themes, Shell Hardware Detection, ICS, System Event Notification Service, Task Scheduler, Background Intelligent Transfer Service, et al.

The CPU usage remains the same at 91% even when I turn off wi-fi (so it's not related to Internet activity). It doesn't seem to be related to disk activity as that's very low (0 to 2%).

I've cleared all of the Event Logs to make sure the services weren't taking too much time writing to very big event logs (they weren't very big to start with anyway). Before doing that, I checked for any tell-tale signs in the event logs and didn't find anything important.

One post suggested that a problem with a device driver (`StorAHCI.sys`) can cause high CPU usage in `svchost.exe`. I've checked and this laptop is not using this driver, it's using `iastor.sys`.

Can you give me any further pointers to investigate the cause?

Comment: It may not be 'active' internet activity, but a miner would show this kind of usage... possibly? I'd suggest backing up the users data, and reinstalling windows 10 after backing up the key (or associating it to a Microsoft account).

Comment: look if you have [this issue](https://superuser.com/q/1260614/174557)

Comment: Thanks, @magicandre1981. The Internet Connection Sharing service is stuck in the "Starting" state, just like in the linked question. I'll try disabling it.

Comment: I've just voted to close my own question. The post that @magicandre1981 linked has fixed this issue. Thanks! One remaining question is why does the ICS keep getting stuck in the Starting state, but that's a different issue.

Comment: it was already closed as duplicate. nice to hear that you were able to fix it with the [steps from the other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1261114/174557)