# Windows 10 "Service Host: Local Service (No Network)" drains CPU constantly

Tags: windows-10, cpu

I've had this problem for at least several months. 
I noticed a lot of threads without a happy ending:

1. [High CPU Usage from "Service Host: Local Service [...]](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-2965897/high-cpu-usage-service-host-local-service.html)
2. [Service Host: Local Service (No Network) (3) and Service Host: Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) causing High CPU](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/service-host-local-service-no-network-3-and/6e55681d-13bb-4638-956d-676161e6eba5)
3. [svchost.exe Service Host: Local Service (No Network) - Permanent CPU usage](https://www.windows10forums.com/threads/svchost-exe-service-host-local-service-no-network-permanent-cpu-usage.13063/)
4. [service host: Local Service (No Network) (5) taking up all my CPU resources (i5-4690k)](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/3v0jb3/service_host_local_service_no_network_5_taking_up/)

And I did try all the suggestions made in these threads including:

1. Updating the windows to the latest version
2. Troubleshoot network, update, etc
3. killing all other software, changing MSISUPPORTED of my SSD disk in regedit etc.

One thing I noticed is that the problem disappears in safemode.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by **restoring Windows Defender Firewall** to **default settings**, as mentioned in [this post](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/95844-fall-update-v-1709-creates-problems-cpu-usage-desktop-wallpaper-5.html).
A very nice explanation and debugging is also given in [this superuser reply](https://superuser.com/a/1261114/228730).

I think some problematic software had access to network. After this reset, windows pops up "Windows Security Alert" again, asking for network privileges, on opening most software for the first time.

[image: Screenshot of restoring the Windows Defender Firewall settings]

Comment: Your answer does not explain the cause.

Comment: True. I'm guessing a buggy software had access to network. Since after this reset, on opening almost every software (first time) it pops up the window security alert asking for network privileges (private/public network): like the one here:
http://www.convertigo.com/wp-content/uploads/doc/openStudio10.jpg