# Service host: local system (network restricted) HIGH CPU

Tags: windows-8.1, high-cpu-usage

I tired everything I could find in the web - nothing is helping.

Long story short: after some uptime of my system, I'm getting my CPU around 90-100%, because the Service host: local system (network restricted) process.

It has inside of it the following running things:
1) WLAN AutoConfig
2) Distributed Link Tracking client
3) Program Compatibility assistant service
4) Network connection Broker
5) Human interface device service
6) Windows audio endpoint builder

Do you have any idea how I can fix this issue and what is actually the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: I would probably run Process Explorer (Sysinternals) and look at the threads of the process that are most active from a CPU perspective, this will help you understand which service or service are the culprit.  Other options would be to run each in it's own process to help pinpoint which service(s) are causing the CPU usage - https://superuser.com/questions/860117/isolate-hosted-service-svchost-exe-in-its-own-process

Answer (score 1):

To determine which service is responsible for the high CPU use, force the services running in the shared instance of svchost.exe to use their own instance of svchost.exe. This will permit you to view each service's CPU use separately.  Do this with the command (from an elevated Command Prompt):

```
sc config <servicename> type= own
```

**Note:** The space in `type= own` is intentional.

For example, to run the WLAN AutoConfig Service service in its own instance of svchost.exe, run:

```
sc config wlansvc type= own
```

Using a process of elimination, isolate several services until you find the one causing the high CPU use. To return a service to the default "shared" instance of svchost.exe, use the command:

```
sc config <servicename> type= share
```